# How to store MM/YYYY date on PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, datetime, database-design

I need to store a date on MM/YYYY format (without the day) on PostgreSQL.
Is that possible?

I don't want to just pick a day and store the day as well because that would be an incorrect information.

thanks.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166117/separate-month-and-year-columns-or-date-with-day-always-set-to-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mm/yyyy` is not a valid `date`. The day is part of it, and cannot be removed. One alternative would to store the data in a string datatype instead of `date`, but I would not recommend that: doing so exposes you to data integrity issues (something like `13/2010`, for example, is not a valid date part).

For this reason, I would still recommend using the `date` datatype. You can just ignore the day when accessing the data, if that's not relevant for you. You can also create a computed column based on the date, that displays the information in the format you want:

```
create table mytabnle (
     ...
     mydate date,
     mystr text geneated always as (to_char(mydate, 'mm/yyyy')) stored
);
```